# How to extract json array elements in postgresql

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

**What I want to do is sum 29.0 and 34.65 and group by P_id**

```
Table: transaction_items
Column name: Debits, P_id
Column data type: text, text
```

Data:

---

### Debits

```
[{"amount":29.0,"description":"Fee_Type_1"}
[{"amount":"34.65","description":"Fee_Type_1"}
```

---

### P_id

```
16
16
```

---

I tried using the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834482/how-to-get-elements-from-json-array-in-postgresql)

```
select     transaction_line_items.P_id,
           each_attribute ->> 'amount' Rev
from       transaction_line_items
cross join json_array_elements(to_json(Debits)) each_section
cross join json_array_elements(each_section -> 'attributes') each_attribute
where      (each_attribute -> 'amount') is not null;
```

However, I got an error saying "cannot deconstruct a scalar".

Can someone please let me know how to parse the values I am looking for?

Comment: the link is useful, but did not show as a clickable link. I tried to edit this, and while editing the preview showed a clickable link, but not after saving the edit. Using Firefox. Feel free to reverse or improve my edit :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that your data is broken. The values of `Debits` column are not valid json due to the lack of right square brackets. Assuming that your data should look like this:

```
[{"amount":29.0,"description":"Fee_Type_1"}]
[{"amount":"34.65","description":"Fee_Type_1"}]
```

the following query does what you want:

```
select p_id, sum(amount)
from (
    select p_id, (elements->>'amount')::numeric amount
    from transaction_items
    cross join json_array_elements(debits::json) elements
    ) sub
group by p_id;
```